# how to write a mapping function that takes in a string of json payload and another string of mappings and returns a string of the mapped data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to write mapping function that takes in a string of json payload and another string of mappings and returns a string of the mapped data. For example a payload of:

```
{
    "Name" : "Hello",
    "This" : {
        "That" : {
            "TheOther" : "There"
        }
    }
}
```

And a map of:

```
 {
    "Test_Name" : "Name",
    "Test_Value" : "This.That.TheOther"
 }
```

Should return:

```
 {
    "Test_Name" : "Hello",
    "Test_Value" : "There"
 }
```

Comment: Your map would contain an arbitrarily amount of properties?

Comment: Use a JSON seriaizer (like json.net), parse the JSON (once you make it valid JSON, as your sample is not) and traverse the parsed result to collect the data you are interested in.  As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: From where would your map actually come, would this also be a json object, or an anonymous object, or some poco class from which you would read the available properties?

Comment: Sorry that why I am confused and asked here I don't have more context about it just I need only mapping function which string of json payload and return it to two value  like 
    "Test_Name" : "Hello",
    "Test_Value" : "There"
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would as comments suggested would have to convert the Json in a usable structure, a common library used for that would be [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) which is available on nuget, and you could then parse your input like in the following way

```
var sourceObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( jsonContent );
var sourceMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>( jsonMap );
```

You would then have the object as a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), and then you could parse it in the following way

```
private static IDictionary<string,object> MapData( JObject source, IDictionary<string,string> map ) {
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var kvp in map) {
        result.Add( kvp.Key, source.SelectToken( kvp.Value ).Value<object>() );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which would return you a dictionary with a key and the value for what you have found, which could then be used further on in your program.

The running version of this program can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKhpgE), but I also provide you with the code in case you just want to copy paste it

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static IDictionary<string,object> MapData( JObject source, IDictionary<string,string> map ) {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var kvp in map) {
            result.Add( kvp.Key, source.SelectToken( kvp.Value ).Value<object>() );
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonContent = @"{
    ""Name"" : ""Hello"",
    ""This"" : {
        ""That"" : {
            ""TheOther"" : ""There""
        }
    }
}";
        string jsonMap = @"{
    ""Test_Name"" : ""Name"",
    ""Test_Value"": ""This.That.TheOther""
 }";
        var sourceObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( jsonContent );
        var sourceMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>( jsonMap );

        var result = MapData( sourceObject, sourceMap );
        foreach (var kvp in result) {
            Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Icepickle for your help that is awesome and it been very bad context of question I will try ti ask more related question. thanks:-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you keep the JPaths in the mapping JSON.

You can load orignal JSON in jobject1. 
You can load mapping JSON to jobject2.

The the loop like below should help you to get the reasult

**Assumption - i am assuming that your map JSON will contain map of only one object and your original JSON would contain array of elements.**

```
for each object in jobject1
  for each object in jobject2
     for each property in object
       get the value field (which would be JPath referring to some location in jobject1).
       set the value field to value of JPath
     end for
  end for
end for
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessed at the json structure for finding the first name. But this is similar to how I would try and do it. If the structure is a little different let me know and I can help.

```
string json = "{data:[{'Name':'Hello','This':{'That':{'TheOther':'There'}}},{'Name':'Hello2','This':{'That':{'TheOther':'There2'}}}]}";

var jsonArray = JToken.Parse(json);    
var selectedObject = jsonArray.SelectToken("$..[?(@.Name== 'Hello')]");
var result = selectedObject.ToString();

var value = JObject.Parse(result);
var selectedValue = value.SelectToken("This.That.TheOther");
var final = selectedValue.ToString();
```